# I'm creating a shopping cart program and I have a few questions regarding the arguments

Tags: python-3.x

```
class store:
    tax = 0.1

    def __init__(self, name: str, price: float, quantity=0):
        assert(price >= 0), f"Price {price} is invalid"
        assert (quantity >= 0), f"Quantity {quantity} is invalid"

        self.mainQ = None
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity

    # def calculate_total_price(self):
    #     print(self.price * self.quantity * store.tax + self.price * self.quantity)
    #     return self.price * self.quantity * store.tax + (self.price * self.quantity)

    # def Update(self, mainQ):
    #     self.mainQ = self.quantity

# Index is the index of the quantity you want to buy
    def purchase(self, index):
        a = self.price * self.quantity * store.tax + self.price * self.quantity
        itemData["quantity"][index] = self.mainQ - self.quantity

        return a, itemData

itemData = {
    "Item": ["Book", "Laptop", "Phone"],
    "Quantity": [10, 15, 5],
    "Price": [2.5, 100, 50]
}

b = store.purchase(1)
```

Would I have to include index into my **init** method in order to access it (When I hover over 'b = store.purchase(1)') it says "parameter 'index' unfilled".

Do I have any missing arguments that would cause the program to be un-callable?

Am I properly updating my quantity argument (I wanted to update my quantity argument based off of the quantity that the user selects to purchase.

Sorry if my questions are poorly formatted first time using Stack Overflow.

Edit:

I also tried creating an instance of my purchase method by doing `b = store.purchase(itemData["Item"][0], itemData["Price"][0], itemData["Quantity"][0])` and it says "unexpected argument" after I add the Quantity key-pair values.

Comment: You need to create an instance to call methods on it - e.g. `store(...).purchase(...)`. Conventionally classes have `PascalCase` names and their instances have `snake_case` names to make the distinction clear.

Answer (score 0):

As given by jonrsharpe,

> You need to create an instance to call methods on it - e.g. `store(...).purchase(...)`. Conventionally classes have PascalCase names and their instances have snake_case names to make the distinction clear

TLDR;

just do it via

```py
    test = store(name=itemData["Item"][0],price=itemData["Price"][0],quantity=itemData["Quantity"][0]) #insert test name, price and index here
    test.purchase(5) #insert test index here
```

also, it is conventional to use `Store` for your class name

Notice: exact reason
The reason why the error `parameter "index" unfilled` is because, normally when you use a method this way:

```py
    item1 = store(...)
    item1.purchase(...)
```

, the `self` parameter is automaticly set to the instance on which the method is executed, etc `item1`. when you execute via
`store.purchase(...)`, `self` is not set, so you need to actually set it yourself. It is still recommended to execute methods via the first syntax.

Edit: after seeing your edit, you have to initialize the instance first, etc via `store(...)`. As said, `purchase()` only has `index` and `self` as arguments.